Android : sound recognition release version
I know that sound recognition feature was introduced on iOS 14.
But what about android ?
When was it released on Android ?
Thank you

Are you referring to this feature: https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-sound-recognition-iphf2dc33312/ios To me that seems like something not accessible to third-party apps. Android does have https://developer.android.com/media/platform/sharing-audio-input but do check the rules/scenarios for which app is allow mic access.
